# Dangerous URL blocked on Magento checkout by Kapersky Internet Security Scanner

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, security

Iam running a website on Magento 1.9.2.2 and I've spotted that checkout pages of this website are being blocked by Kaspersky Internet security Software.
This issue happened to myself and also was reported by several customers.

When going trough the checkout from Selecting delivery method to Payment method Iam kicked out by my Kaspersky Internet security with pop-up message "Dangerous URL blocked.
and Iam redirected back to shopping cart unable to complete check out.

When I turn off Kaspersky Internet security I can check out OK.

The Kaspersky does not give much details in report, here is all I get:
26.01.2016 11.43.55;Dangerous URL blocked;https://www.domain.com/checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/;https://www.domain.com/checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/;Heuristic Analysis;Google Chrome;01/26/2016 11:43:55

David

Comment: Have you tried contacting Kaspersky on this? Sounds like their heuristics engine is suffering false positives.

Comment: @FiascoLabs Do you have enough rep to create a new tag?  We don't appear to have a version tag for mageno-1.9.2.2 yet, which is the version David is referencing in this question.  I added the existing magento-1.9 tag to the question during my last edit, but if you have enough rep could you create the new version tag so I can clarify the version specifically generating the problem for him in his Kapersky scans?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We ran into the same issue some time ago. What worked was to contact Kaspersky about the issue.
They replied (with some days delay) that they removed the domain from the filter/blacklist and everything works fine again.